# print two lines from multiple files with the file name in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have multiple files in a directory. i want to pull out certain lines from all those files and print to an output file.

File1

```
line1
line2 
line3
line4
```

File2

```
line1
line2 
line3
line4
```

and like so i have many files. 
Desired Output

```
File1
line2
line4
File2
line2
line4
```

I tried

```
awk 'FNR==2 {print FILENAME, $0}' *.txt
```

This prints just line 2. I also tried with `FNR==2 & 4`How do i print two lines here? Ill appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what you want:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { print FILENAME } FNR == 2 || FNR == 4' *.txt
```

At the start of each file, print the filename. Then print, when the line number is 2 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify your  command to

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} (FNR==2||FNR==4) {print $0}' *.txt
1.txt
line2 
line4
2.txt
line2 
line4
```

Comment: Ok, I just correct the logic in his question, correct the answer already. thanks @TomFenech

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun if you have `GNU sed`

```
$ sed -sn '1F;2p;4p' *.txt
file1.txt
line2 
line4
file2.txt
line2 
line4
```

- `-s` to treat input files separately so that they each have their own addressing
- `-n` disable automatic printing
- `1F` print filename if line number is one
- `2p;4p` print 2nd and 4th line